# Fetching Reference Value from Firebase in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am currently struggling to retrieve the data of a specific field from a collection.

This is the structure of my data:
[image]

And my RN code:

```
onEventCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const events = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { user, title, action, verb, latitude, longitude, photo } = doc.data();
      // const data = doc.data();
      events.push({
        id: doc.id,
        title,
        user,
        verb,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        photo
      });
    });
    this.setState({
      events,
      isLoading: false,
   });
  }
```

which is triggered in:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.events.onSnapshot(this.onEventCollectionUpdate);
  }
```

which is defined in my constructor:

```
this.events =  firebase.firestore().collection('events')
```

I can retrieve the data, and when I print user or doc.data(), the results are massive and nearly incomprehensible. The const { user, title... bit works fine, except "user."

User is returned as a referenceValue, but doesn't actually return as if it were a value I can do anything with. It seems to be returning a massive object, which I can't figure out how to deal with.

Since it is a reference, is it returning the full users object? If so, how do I deal with that? If it's not, how do I make use of the user that is returned? Ideally I end up with the data from user, but not sure if I need to make extra calls for that.

Any pointers would be great, thank you!

Comment: Can you show the output of the log of the 'massive object'?

Comment: Also another thing is that `doc.data()` is async, so you should be either awaiting it or using `.then()`.

Comment: Definitely @Colin - Unfortuantely it was truncated, here's the bottom bit that's left. https://pastebin.com/sXBwvFTv

Comment: It's the bit "user": Object {
                                        "referenceValue": "projects/1234/databases/(default)/documents/users/xE8KjxBRaOR5QETttGwu",
                                      }, that I am trying to get

Comment: Here's the beginning @Colin https://pastebin.com/e638kvjr

Comment: It shouldn't be returning a reference — can you try it with a `.then()`?